# wrap deja espacios en blanco y quiero que deje de hacerlo y el container sea adapte pero sin ningun tipo de grid ni porcentaje

Tags: html, css, flex

`wrap` deja espacios en blanco y quiero que deje de hacerlo y el container sea adapte pero sin ningún tipo de grid ni porcentaje.

El tema es que los porcentajes hacen que en las pantallas grandes los containers se vean gigantes y que en las pequeñas enanos, en el html tengo imagenes puestas por eso es necesario el flex. El tema es que necesito poner que el maximo de width sea 407px y el mínimo 330px y que por ejemplo a alguien con una pantalla se le ponga el container de 350px y que en vez de haber 4 container en la misma linea haber 3 y que a otro con la pantalla más grande se le ponga a 405px y que tenga en vede de 4 que tenga 5 en la misma linea.

```css
.all .containers {
  margin-top: 1.9%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 0.9%;
  margin-right: 0.9%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.all .container {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #27272a;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  min-width: 230px;
  width: 407px;
  margin-top: 1.6%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.all .container:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="containers">
    <a class="container">
      <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1061354590177599661/1113910936412110978/image.png" width="auto" height="70%">
      <h1 class="12">Economyshopgui</h1>
      <div>
        <button class="download" onclick="window.location.href='/things/mc/economyshopgui#download'">Download</button>
        <button class="more" onclick="window.location.href='/things/mc/economyshopgui'">See more</button>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes algún HTML integrado?...

Comment: Yes @Cris223511.dev